# multiple touch in xcode iOS objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a character in my game that I can move left/right and jump. I am using touchesBegan to do that. But when I move left ( keep touching the screen -> makes character faster and faster ), it only jumps when i release it. I would like to jump and move left at the same time.

Here is some of my code :

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];


if((point.x < moveLeftButton.frame.size.width))
{

    if((point.y > JumpButton.frame.size.height))
    {
        leftSide = YES;
        sanchez.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"characterL2"];
    }

}


if((point.x) > (backGround.frame.size.width - moveRightButton.frame.size.width))
{

    if((point.y > JumpButton.frame.size.height))
    {
        rightSide = YES;
        sanchez.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"characterR2"];
    }

}

if( notJumping && (point.y < JumpButton.frame.size.height) && (sanchezStopAll == NO))
{
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(jump);
    sanchezJumping = 5.5;
    notJumping = NO;

}

[self animation];
```

}

I am not using buttonPressed because they are hidden and I think you can't click hidden buttons.

This is how it looks like if its not hidden:

[image: view]
Thanks for any Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll only get a single touch by default unless you set [`multipleTouchEnabled = YES`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW34). Then your code should work as expected.

For example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: Could you give me a short example how to implement it?

Comment: @Robin I've added example.

Comment: your answer did help me, i just realized that there is still one little problem: 
if i touch and hold left, he starts running and keeps on going. When I touch jump then, he jumps ( thats what the multiple touch did) , but he stops running left then

Comment: so , touchesEnded is called when i touch again , even if I didn't release the first touch,