# TouchUpInside doesn't recognize more than one click

Tags: c#, swift, xamarin.ios, touch-up-inside

The `nextButton` only responds to the first click.

Do I need to implement something else to recognize more clicks?

```
nextButton.TouchUpInside += (s, e) =>
{

};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiple touch in xcode iOS objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142109/multiple-touch-in-xcode-ios-objective-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `nextButton.MultipleTouchEnabled = true` (or, in Swift 3, `nextButton.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true`) to allow multiple touches to be processed at once.